# Invalid Hook Call Full Stack Open 2021 Phonebook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React.

I am trying to use Filter component but it is giving me this error: "**Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**"

I think the problem is somewhere in the **onChange={handleFilterChange}** but I do not know what. Any clues?

Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Filter from './components/Filter'
import Person from './components/Person'

const App = () => {
    const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
        { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '040-123456' },
        { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523' },
        { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345' },
        { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122' }
    ])
    const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
    const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState('')
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('')

    const handleNameChange = (event) => {
        console.log("name", event.target.value)
        setNewName(event.target.value)
    }
    const handleNumberChange = (event) => {
        console.log("number", event.target.value)
        setNewNumber(event.target.value)
    }

    const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
        console.log("filter", event.target.value)
        setFilter(event.target.value)
    }

    const peopleToShow = filter
        ? persons.filter(person => person.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()))
        : persons

    const handleAddPerson = (event) => {
        // prevent default form action
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log('button clicked', event.target);
        console.log("newname", newName)

        let checkNameExists = persons.filter(person => (person.name === newName))
        let checkNumberExists = persons.filter(person => (person.number === newNumber))

        if (checkNameExists.length === 0 && checkNumberExists.length === 0) {
            const nameObject = {
                name: newName,
                number: newNumber
            }
            // dont mutate state. use set method (make new object)
            setPersons(persons.concat(nameObject))
        } else if (checkNameExists.length !== 0) {
            alert(`${newName} is already added to phonebook`);
        } else {
            alert(`${newNumber} is already added to phonebook`);
        }

        // reset name and number
        setNewName('')
        setNewNumber('')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Phonebook</h2>
            <Filter value={filter} onChange={handleFilterChange}/>
            {/* <div>
                filter shown with:<input value={filter}
                    onChange={handleFilterChange} />
            </div> */}

            <h2>add a new contact</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleAddPerson}>
                <div>
                    name:<input value={newName}
                        onChange={handleNameChange} />
                </div>
                <div>number: <input value={newNumber}
                    onChange={handleNumberChange} /></div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">add</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <h2>Numbers</h2>
            <div>
                {peopleToShow.map(person =>
                    <Person key={person.name} person={person} />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Here is my Filter.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const Filter = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            filter shown with:<input value={props.filter}
                onChange={props.handleFilterChange} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Filter
```

Comment: in your Filter component, on the input, use `onChange={props.onChange}`

Comment: @EmileBergeron It doesn't give error now but the filtering does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: With the change I suggested above, it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<Filter value={filter} onChange={handleFilterChange}/>
```

to

```
<Filter filter={filter} handleFilterChange={handleFilterChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not pass the reference of your setFilter func to anywhere else in the props. That's why you've used the **handler** function in the first place.. you should rename the prop. its a better practice.

and then again, in your filter js you should use the prop setFilter that you've passed. you haven't passed **handleFilterChange** func in the props.. you tried to import that func.. but I believe you have not exported it.. and you did not follow the named import convention..

Comment: Edited, can you check again?

Comment: you have passed the prop in the name of onChange. you should call the prop value by the exact same name.. i.e. 
onChange={props.onChange} instead of onChange={props.handleFilterChange} .,

cause you've send the funtion pointed in the prop variable onChange. this onChange is not a dom event listener rather a custom listener to your custom component "Filter" 

there may be some other issues on your code too. but its an obvious one. fix this and try again see if it fixed the issue or not